# Xcode my app won't work in the iPad simulator but works on iPhone simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

this code currently starts out with message saying 'warning may cause seizure' and when you press the message which is a button, the screen will flash a random color. in the mainstory board I dragged the didTapAdd action to the button I made. it works on all iPhone simulators but when I'm on the iPad and I press the message nothing happens. how can this be ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .magenta, .darkGray, .gray, .lightGray, .brown, .cyan
    ]
    
    var label: UILabel?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
        let label = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "Warning. May cause a seizure."
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        self.label = label /// assign self.label, so we can access it later
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        if let myLabel = label {
            myLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            self.label = nil /// set to nil, so we won't try to remove it again
        }
        
        let color1 = self.colors.randomElement()
        let color2 = self.colors.randomElement()
        
        self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view.backgroundColor = color1 /// set to color1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .black
            self.view.backgroundColor = color2// now animate to color2, reverse, then repeat
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-04-25%20at%2012.59.51%20PM.png)

Comment: thank you for checking it out ! what do u think I am doing wrong or what did u do different? it works it you get it exactly in the middle of the message or to the left of the message depending on what iPad I am using. can I make it so wherever they click on the screen it will work ..thansk!

Comment: Did you add constraints?

Comment: how do u do that can u show me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add constraints -- they are complex, but here's a good [guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started) to get started. However, for your case, simple "align" constraints should work fine.

1. Select your button in the storyboard
2. Check both `Horizontally in Container` and `Vertically in Container`

[image: Check both Horizontally in Container and Vertically in Container]

3. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard
4. See result:

| Storyboard | Device |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Button centered in storyboard view controller, with blue lines indicating centering] | [image] |

Comment: thank you so much but I suck and can't do it :( do u have TeamViewer ?

Comment: @ArashKalhori no, but I have Discord - aheze#3125

Comment: thanks cool I will get it  do you know how to work with flask?

Comment: @ArashKalhori nope